# Draw a program dependence graph with graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to draw a PDG, but when I add the data dependencies it gets malformed.

### What I have

When I only draw the control dependencies the graph looks fine:

```
digraph {
4[label="4. int x=1"];
5[label="5. int y=2"];
6[label="6. while(x>0)"];
8[label="8. x=(y+x)"];
10[label="10. z=x+y"];
ENTRY -> 4[rank=same, splines=line];
ENTRY -> 5[rank=same, splines=line];
ENTRY -> 6[rank=same, splines=line];
ENTRY -> 10[rank=same, splines=line];
6 -> 8[splines=line];
}
```

[image: Only Control dependencies]

When I try to add the data dependencies the graph gets malformed:

```
digraph {
4[label="4. int x=1"];
5[label="5. int y=2"];
6[label="6. while(x>0)"];
8[label="8. x=(y+x)"];
10[label="10. z=x+y"];
ENTRY -> 4[rank=same, splines=line];
ENTRY -> 5[rank=same, splines=line];
ENTRY -> 6[rank=same, splines=line];
ENTRY -> 10[rank=same, splines=line];
6 -> 8[splines=line];
4 -> 6[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
8 -> 6[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
4 -> 8[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
5 -> 8[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
4 -> 10[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
5 -> 10[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
8 -> 10[style=dashed, splines=curved, color=red];
}
```

[image: With data dependencies]

I tried to add the attribute "splines=line" to draw straight lines (control dep.), but it doesnt't worked like expected. I also experimented with the attribute "weight" and "rank"...

Can someone give me a hint? Is it possible to set an order for the nodes?
Like:
Entry = first row and first element
Node 4 = second row and first element
...
Node 8 = third row and first element

### Expected

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rank = same` properly, plus invisible edges to keep the order of the nodes in the middle should help:

```
digraph so
{
    splines=true;

    4[label="4. int x=1"];
    5[label="5. int y=2"];
    6[label="6. while(x>0)"];
    8[label="8. x=(y+x)"];
    10[label="10. z=x+y"];

    { rank = same; 4 5 6 10 }
    ENTRY -> { 4 5 6 10 }
    6 -> 8;

    edge[style=dashed, color=red];
    { 4 8 } -> 6;
    { 4 5 } -> 8;
    { 4 5 8 } -> 10;
    // keep graphViz from re-ordering these nodes:
    4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 10[ style = invis ];
}
```

yields

[image]